# Binding value of custom control to selectmethod repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, model-binding

I have a problem with binding the value of a custom control to the select method of a repeater.

This is an example, I need this to explain my problem:
there is a **dropdownList** & a **repeater** with **SelectMethod GetMedicationTransferIncomingView**

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="DisplayYear" runat="server"> 
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Repeater ID="stockGridIncoming" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetMedicationTransferIncomingView" ItemType="Ihc.Medicatiebeheer.Service.ViewModels.MedicationTransferIncomingView">
</asp:Repeater>

Public Function GetMedicationTransferIncomingView(<Control> displayYear As String) As IEnumerable(Of MedicationTransferIncomingView)

End Function
```

So this works, the controller with id **DisplayYear** is given to the **GetMedicationTransferIncomingView** as displayYear. With this I can update my repeater depening on what I choose in my dropdownlist, great!

Now problem! I want to replace the dropdownlist with a custom control, so I try this the same way like I did with the dropdownlist, only when the selection in my custom control changes, the select-method of my repeater isn't called.

This is probably due the wrong call of ID, If I inspect the ID's in my browser, the Id of my dropdownlist is: **MainContent_DisplayYear**

The Id of my custom control is this: **SiteMaster_MainContent_VeDropDownFrom_VeDropDown**

This is the code, the same way I did it with the dropdown, only now it does not work!

```
 <ihc:VerpleegEenheidDropDown ID="VeDropDownFrom" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">

</ihc:VerpleegEenheidDropDown>


Public Function GetMedicationTransferOutgoingView(<Control> veDropDownFrom As String) As IEnumerable(Of MedicationTransferOutgoingView)

End Function
```